# 2d path "shrink-wrap" algorithms

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, shrinkwrap

Suppose we are given some 2d path geometry. Is there an algorithm that could produce a new path that "wraps" the geometry in a similar form as below?

[image: Original path = GREY. New path = RED]

The effect should be similar to how an object looks when it is shrink-wrapped.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, when people say "shrink-wrap" in the context of defining a path or surface, they mean the convex hull. However, that's not what your picture shows, and it's not clear from your picture what you actually mean.

Comment: A concave hull wouldn't even produce the curvature that you have shown in the void areas.  This looks like a rule set in between the two.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I think the idea of such an alogrithm is, that a circular "shrink-wrap-foil" is placed around the object and pulled towards surface normal (or something else, like the barycenter). Then there are two possibilities: either the foil touches a convex part or a concave one (i.e. hole). The convex part is easy, as the foil can not penetrate the object. On the concave parts, the foil reaches as far down as some energy criterion (i.e. surface tension vs "gravity") lets it. When truly minimizing surface tension, you would get the convex hull.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using quadratic splines with anchors at the vertices at the start of a concave area, and a control point at a location inside the concave area.

The control point location will have to be determined based on the local geometry.

something like this, maybe?

[image]

The algorithm could be:

```
1- find the convex hull  
2- for each concave segment (where the convex hull doesn't match the polygon path):  
    2a - id the start and end point as anchors  
    2b - id a control point position
    2c - trace a quadratic spline using these points
```